# Retrieving a param that is a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

I am passing a hash as a parameter from a view to another view through a form. I verified the contents of the hash in the first view, and I can see that it has been sent based on the URL in the second view, however, I cannot seem to access it from the controller.

My code looks something like this:

View #1 (sortday.html.erb):

```
<% @type_hash = Hash.new
  @type_hash["arr"] = @type_array %>

<%= form_tag({:controller => 'options', :action => 'sort', :event_hash => @type_hash, :page =>     1}, :method => 'get') do %>
            <%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => 'day', order: [:month, :day, :year] %>
            <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Type hash is set to:

```
{"arr"=>["[321, 82]", "[88, 84]", "[960, 45]"]}
```

Controller (options_controller.rb):

```
def sort
    @hash = Hash.new
    @hash = params[:event_hash]
end
```

View #2 (sort.html.erb):

```
 HASH = <%= @hash %>
```

When I submit the form, the url looks something like this:

```
".../events/sort/**arr%5B%5D=%5B321%2C+82%5D&arr%5B%5D=%5B88%2C+84%5D&arr%5B%5D=%5B960%2C+45%5D**/1?utf8=✓&day%5Bmonth%5D=7...commit=Submit"
```

As you can see, the hash makes it into the URL.  How do I retrieve it in the controller/view?

I have also tried such things as:

```
@hash = params[:event_hash][:arr]
```

and

```
@hash = params[:arr]
```

to no avail.

Comment: What do i get where? As the value for @hash? Currently, through any one of those methods listed above @hash is either never set, or set to nil

Comment: and what does `params` have?

Comment: Oh my god, your a genius. Why didnt i think to look at params -.-
It looks like I had excess variables in my routes.rb which led to type_hash being assigned to a different parameter then I originally sent. Looking at params, i was able to retrieve the value of type_hash and use it in the view. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my routes had excess variables that were not being used which led to my parameters being offset when they were assigned.

Looking at the value of parameters showed that `@type_hash` was being assigned to `param[:type]` instead of `param[:event_hash]`.